# Argo CD pod can't pull the image

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I'm running a hybrid AKS cluster where I have one Linux and one Windows node. The Windows node will run a legacy server app. I want to use Argo CD to simplify the deployments.

After following the installation [instructions](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/getting_started/) ([installation manifest](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml)) and installing Argo in the cluster I noticed I can't connect to its dashboard.

Troubleshooting the issue I found that the Argo pod can't pull the image. Below output of `kubectl describe pod  argocd-server-75b6967787-xfccz -n argocd`

[image]

[image]

Another thing that is visible here is that Argo pod got assigned to a windows node. From what I found here, Argo can't run on windows nodes. I think that's the root cause of the problems.

Does anyone know how can I force Argo pods to run on Linux node?

I [found](https://argoproj.github.io/argo/windows/) that something like `nodeSelector` could be useful.

```
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
```

But how could I apply the `nodeSelector` on the already deployed Argo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `nodeSelector` to the pod templates of `argocd-server`, `argocd-repo-server` and `argocd-application-controller` workloads (former two are `Deployment`, the latter is a `StatefulSet`).

After that I redeployed the manifests. The images got pulled and I was able to access the Argo dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Does anyone know how can I force Argo pods to run on Linux node?

check for the other node label and change the node selector

```
nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
```

you can directly edit the current deployment of argo CD

```
kubectl edit deployment argocd-server -n <namespace name>
```

you can edit the label directly using cli and update it